# Send Email To Multiple Recipients In DataTable

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I want to add all emails in my datatable to the To: of my email - I have tried the below code, but it adds a semi-colon after each char in the email address.  How do I need to re-write this so that each email address is added?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in datatatblefirst.Rows)  
{
  foreach (char eadd in r["Email"].ToString())
  {
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMsg.HTMLBody = "Body";
    oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
    Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
    foreach (char email in r["Email"].ToString())
      oRecips.Add(eadd.ToString());
    oMsg.Save();
    oRecip = null;
    oRecips = null;
    oMsg = null;
    oApp = null; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are iterating over each `char` in an email address.

If `r["Email"]` contains one email address you can just loop over the data rows.  The code below will create one email message per email address:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in datatatblefirst.Rows)  
{  
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    oMsg.HTMLBody = "Body";
    oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
    Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;

    string emailAddress = r["Email"].ToString();
    Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(emailAddress);
    oRecip.Resolve();

    oMsg.Save();
    //oMsg.Send();
    oRecip = null;
    oRecips = null;
    oMsg = null;
    oApp = null; 
}
```

To create only one email and send to multiple addresses, create the email before the `foreach`:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
oMsg.HTMLBody = "Body";
oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;

foreach (DataRow dr in datatatblefirst.Rows)  
{  
    string emailAddress = r["Email"].ToString();
    Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(emailAddress);
    oRecip.Resolve();
}

oMsg.Save();
//oMsg.Send();
oRecips = null;
oMsg = null;
oApp = null;
```

The line `oRecip.Resolve();` is not required.  If the contact exists in the address book it will format the email address as `Some Name <somename@email.com>`.

The addresses can be added simply using `oRecips.Add(emailAddress);` without creating or resolving the `Recipient` object.

Comment: @DoctorFord It tries to resolve the recipient  name against the address book.  It's probably not needed. The [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.resolve?view=outlook-pia)

Comment: It would put the string into the format `Some One <someone@email.com>` if the contact exists in the address book